# Babel not transpiling

Tags: babeljs, gulp-babel

I'm using babel from gulp to attempt to create React code.

When I run babel either from gulp or just from the commandline, the output of my code is exactly the same as the input. Nothing is changed.

This is my babel.config.js

```
const presets = [
    [
        "@babel-env",
        {
            targets : {
                edge : "17",
                ie  : "8",
                firefox : "60",
                chrome : "67",
                safari : "11.1"
            },
            useBuiltIns: "usage"
        }
    ],
]
```

This is the contents of the  file I want to transform:

```
import React from 'react' ;
import ReactDOM from 'react-dom';

console.log("starting...");

const foo = "foo" ;
const bar = "bar"

const testFn =  (foo, bar) => {
    console.log("in testFn");
}
```

This is my task definition:

```
gulp.task('scripts', function() {
    return gulp.src(['./src/js/main.js' ])
        .pipe(babel({
            presets : ['@babel/preset-react']
        }))
        .pipe(concat('test.js'))
        .pipe(gulp.dest('./dist/js'))
        .pipe(terser())
        .pipe(rename('test.min.js'))
        .pipe(gulp.dest('./dist/js')) ;
});
```

How do I get babel to do its job?